# Crystal reports repeating the items when i am using the query with dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to crystal report. At the time of binding the data from dataset to the crystal report showing twice or thrice.

I am using SQL 2005 and VS 2008.

i checked in SQL and dataset also at the time of debugging but in dataset only i am having 5 records but in my crystal its showing 10 records.

Below is my Code:

```
ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();

sda = new SqlDataAdapter(" SELECT ac_mstr.AC_DESC, TRAN_HDR.DOC_DT, TRAN_DTLS.GL_CODE,    DBCR, AMT FROM dbo.TRAN_DTLS TRAN_DTLS INNER JOIN dbo.AC_MSTR ac_mstr ON (TRAN_DTLS.SUB_CODE=ac_mstr.SUB_CODE) AND (TRAN_DTLS.GL_CODE=ac_mstr.GL_CODE) INNER JOIN dbo.TRAN_HDR TRAN_HDR ON (TRAN_DTLS.TC=TRAN_HDR.TC) AND (TRAN_DTLS.DOC_NO=TRAN_HDR.DOC_NO) where tran_hdr.tc='CAS' and tran_hdr.doc_dt between '2012/01/01' and '2012/12/30'   ORDER BY TRAN_DTLS.GL_CODE", con);

        sda.Fill(ds);      
       doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Acc_sum.rpt"));

      doc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
      CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
```

Can any one help Me?

Comment: If I was to guess I would say that your Crystal report has the information required to contact the SQL server baked in, so your data set is the first set  of values, and the ones from the server is your second.  I can not tell though without your crystal report and more time then I have.  You also might have values saved in the report.  Try running SQL profiler to see if crystal report is querying the database.  Try opening the crystal report in an editor/viewer to see if it has data saved in it (or try changing the data on the server to see if you get dups of the new values).

Comment: In crystal report at the time of preview its contains single record but at run time only its having the duplicate data. How to run the SQL profiler for crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

the mistake came from your query:

```
    SELECT ac_mstr.AC_DESC, TRAN_HDR.DOC_DT, TRAN_DTLS.GL_CODE,    DBCR, AMT 
FROM dbo.TRAN_DTLS TRAN_DTLS INNER JOIN dbo.AC_MSTR ac_mstr
 ON (TRAN_DTLS.SUB_CODE=ac_mstr.SUB_CODE) AND (TRAN_DTLS.GL_CODE=ac_mstr.GL_CODE) 
INNER JOIN dbo.TRAN_HDR TRAN_HDR ON (TRAN_DTLS.TC=TRAN_HDR.TC) AND (TRAN_DTLS.DOC_NO=TRAN_HDR.DOC_NO) where tran_hdr.tc='CAS' and tran_hdr.doc_dt between '2012/01/01' and '2012/12/30'   ORDER BY TRAN_DTLS.GL_CODE
```

which make your data appear twice so change your query .

Comment: K But This query return the values once.  At the time of debugging i checked in dataset. In dataset it showing all the values one at a time but at the time of viewing in crystal its contains double

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports can do unexpected thing with data.  A great place to start debugging (besides opening the crystal report in an editor and clicking around) is to use SQL Server Profiler.  A more detailed tutorial can be found at http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3750161/Introduction-to-SQL-2005-Profiler-Part-1.htm.

It is important to note that while SQL Server 2005 Express can be used with SQL Server Pro filer, it does not come bundled with the program.

I have attached a basic set of directions for your convenience:

-

1. Open SQL Server Profiler:

   - From the start menu: \All Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2005\Performance Tools\SQL Server Profiler.
   - From SQL Server Management Studio: Tools\SQL Server Profiler
2. Press the new trace button which is the left most button on the tool bar.
3. Connect to the SQL server which is hosting your data.
4. On the Trace Properties screen press the run button.
   (Their are a number of usuful features on the Events Selection tab, but for your purposes the default settings should be fine.)
5. Run your program.

Using the default settings you should be able to see when ever anything accesses your database, and what queries they use to do the accessing.  This way you can see if your query is correct or if there are other issues.

I have also seen (rarely) in the past crystal reports performing a local join on the data which resulted in duplicates.  When this has happened to me I have had to remove large chunks of the report, or even create a new report and test it at each step, to determine where the issue is.

Please let me know if you require additional assistance.